# Random Forest Prediction

Tags: r, random-forest, prediction

Consider the following problem.
You have a large simulated dataset of epidemic curves labels from the classes M1, M2, M4..M24.

where in the epidemic curves `t1 t2 t3 t4...` time in days and the observations are the counts of infected cases per day.

```
ID    t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 t11 t12 t13 t14 t15  Y

1328  1  2  2  1  0  1  0  0  1   0   1   0   0   1   1  M7
3564  1  2  3  2  2  1  2  3  1   1   0   0   1   0   0  M18
1601  1  1  3  3  1  2  1  2  1   1   0   0   0   1   0  M9
1897  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0  M10
708   1  1  1  1  1  2  1  3  2   1   0   2   0   1   0  M4
1313  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0   1   0   0   0   0   1 M 7
2283  1  8  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0 M12
536   1  9  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0 M 3
,
,
,
```

ONE epidemic curve obtained from a real dataset of which I would like to predict the unseen label “Y” using random forest in R.  Since the test set is based on real data, I can’t generate multiple epidemic curves like I did with the train set.
The test set looks like this:

```
ID      t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 t10 t11 t12 t13 t14 t15 Y
21000  1  1  2  7  6  1  3  4  2   2   4   3   3   1   1 ?
```

Questions:
1: what are good approaches one can take to this kind of problem since I only have one epidemic curve to predict? How I will be able to create confusion matrix for prediction one test set?

2: how to validate RF result of the predicted label since I originally don't know the true label of the test set? For example, if RF predict the label “Y” of the test set to be M7, how accurate this prediction is since I don’t have an idea of the true labels of my tex set?

Comment: Please include some sample data, and let us know what the dependent and independent variables are.

Comment: I did thank you. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: what is an "epidemic" curve?

Comment: Thank you. just edit it epidemic curves `t1 t2 t3 t4...` time in days and the observations are the counts of infected cases per day.